# How do I make old rails plugins work in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm porting an old rails 2.1.1 app to rails 4. It relies on several plugins that have no gem equivalents. How would I get these working in rails 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [explained in the release note](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html), you have two options

1. Package the plugin as a gem
2. Embed the plugin inside the /lib folder of your app

I would personally use this particular event to review the list of plugins my app depends on. If the plugin has not been converted into a gem, there are several possible cases

1. The plugin is unmaintained. A good reason to replace it.
2. The plugin is no longer necessary, the feature may be provided (may be in a different shape) by Rails itself
3. The plugin may not be necessary any longer. A good reason to replace it.
4. If you really find a good reason to keep it and for whatever good reason there is no gem for that, use one of the solutions above.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and accurate response!